# Alternative to GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I have the table with `billID` being the primary key:

`Invoice (billID, item, value, quantity)`

and the following query:

```
SELECT item, sum(quantity) AS TotalItems
FROM Invoice
WHERE value>1
GROUP BY item
HAVING sum(quantity)>10
```

I need to rewrite to *optimize* (or *de-optimize*?) using only `SELECT`, `FROM` and `WHERE`.

1. What is the new query eliminating `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`?
2. Is it always possible to eliminate `GROUP BY` & `HAVING` and use only `SELECT`, `FROM` and `WHERE`?

**My approach:**

[1] I am using `UNION` of different `items` to achieve this. But the major problem is that I need to know all the `item` before hand.

```
SELECT item, sum(quantity) FROM Invoice WHERE item='lumia'
UNION
SELECT item, sum(quantity) FROM Invoice WHERE item='iphone'
UNION
SELECT item, sum(quantity) FROM Invoice WHERE item='samsung'
UNION
SELECT item, sum(quantity) FROM Invoice WHERE item='moto'
.
.
.
and so on
```

Is there another way to get the result?

Comment: What is wrong with your original query?  I think it is the most optimized solution for your problem.

Comment: @sgeddes I agree. But I need analyse the query without `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

Comment: @sam: why? What particular problem are you trying to solve? Are you having performance issues? Is this an interview brain-teaser? Homework problem? Are you just curious? I can't think of a good reason why you'd want to use anything other than GROUP BY. The alternatives are generally slower and certainly less flexible.

Comment: @siride Well, that's kind of a brain teaser we were trying to solve using nested queries!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

we can use subquery and do summation of each item's quantity

```
SELECT A.item, A.Total
FROM
(  SELECT distinct item,
       (SELECT SUM(quantity)
        FROM Invoice I2 
        WHERE I2.item = I1.item) Total
FROM Invoice I1
) A
where Total >10
```

Comment: +1 -- I like this approach better than mine, but I would say that it still uses aggregation which utilizes `group by` (even if the `group by` clause is omitted).

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh and @sgeddes. I guess this would be an alternative to `GROUP BY` in every case but quite complex to write!

Comment: My guess is that this would have the same execution plan as the `GROUP BY` version.

Answer (score 1):

While I would ***never*** recommend doing it this way, MySql does support user defined variables.  So you technically could rewrite your query to sum the items in a variable, establish a row number to get the max, then select only the highest total per group (per item):

```
select item, totalitems
from (
  select 
    item, totalitems, @rn:=IF(@previtem=item,@rn+1,1) rn, @previtem:=item
  from (
    select item,
      @qtytotal:=(IF(@previtem=item,@qtytotal+quantity,quantity)) totalitems,
      @previtem:=item
    from invoice, (select @qtytotal:=0, @previtem:='') t
    where value > 1 
    order by item
    ) t, (select @rn:=0, @previtem:='') s
  where totalitems > 10
  order by item, totalitems desc
  ) t
where rn = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3b0f/13)

---

This is written with the concept of only using `select`, `from` and `where` -- no aggregations such as `sum` which technically utilizes `group by` with or without the clause.